# polars assign to multiple columns

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to understand if there is any way to do when..then..otherwise in polars and assign to multiple columns.   I have a elo dataset with millions of rows where I want to assign the current elo to anything greater than date.
In pandas, I would do

```
elo_df.loc[(id, date:)), ["elo", "true_skill_mu", "true_skill_sigma"]] = elo, true_skill_mu, true_skill_sigma
```

The code below works but is very slow. I am hoping I can increase the speed by at least 3x by making the filter happen once.  Also, if have any suggestion on to how tomake this faster, please let me know.

```
elo_df = elo_df.with_columns([pl.when((pl.col("id") == col) & (pl.col("date") >= date)).then(pl.lit(new_rating)).otherwise(pl.col("elo")).alias("elo"),
                                           
pl.when((pl.col("id") == col) & (pl.col("date") >= date)).then(pl.lit(new_mu)).otherwise(pl.col("true_skill_mu")).alias("true_skill_mu"),
                                            pl.when((pl.col("id") == col) & (pl.col("date") >= date)).then(pl.lit(new_sigma)).otherwise(pl.col("true_skill_sigma")).alias("true_skill_sigma")]
```

Comment: Since they are in a `with_columns` context, the three when/then/otherwise expressions will run in parallel (as long as your CPU has at least 3 cores).  So from a wall-clock standpoint, you will not gain much by trying to rewrite them as one filter.  That said, are you updating large batches of id's at one time?  If so, then there is a speed-up for that.

Comment: I am updating one id at a time

Comment: @cbilot Is there a faster way to update than these filters?

Comment: Hmm, I'm somewhat puzzled.  I created a dataset of 605 million records, and ran the three when/then/otherwise expressions are you described.  I'm getting times of about 3-4 seconds.  Are you getting something significantly worse?

Comment: My issue is I am probably doing something silly. I am rolling thru each date and updating all going forward on each date

Comment: If you can post your code along with a mock dataset of about 10 records and a description of what you’re trying to achieve, I might be able to help.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MichaelWS/c3591a048390de568803e5db7d537e4f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246722/discussion-between-michael-ws-and-cbilot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `polars.col` followed by [polars.Expr.map](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map.html#polars.Expr.map)

```py
def on_when(s : pl.Series, df = elo_df):
    # or pass them as default arguments
    global new_rating, new_mu, new_sigma
    if s.name == "elo":
        return new_rating
    elif s.name == "true_skill_mu":
        return new_mu
    elif s.name == "true_skill_sigma":
        return new_sigma


def otherwise(s : pl.Series, df = elo_df):
    if s.name == "elo":
        return df.get_column("elo")
    elif s.name == "true_skill_mu":
        return df.get_column("true_skill_mu")
    elif s.name == "true_skill_sigma":
        return df.get_column("true_skill_sigma")
    # or you can simply just use `return s` since we are not doing any operations
    # this is just an example if we want to do calculations based on other columns


elo_df = elo_df.with_columns([
    pl.when((pl.col("id") == col) & (pl.col("date") >= date))
    .then(pl.col(["elo", "true_skill_mu", "true_skill_sigma"]).map(on_when))
    .otherwise(pl.col(["elo", "true_skill_mu", "true_skill_sigma"]).map(otherwise))
])
```

Comment: I assume that's faster?

Comment: could  update a bunch of "id"s  at once with map in some way?

Comment: have you tried using [is_in](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.is_in.html?highlight=contain#polars-expr-is-in). I can't guarantee that is is faster

Comment: Yes.  I was testing a giant pandas project in polars and this part is the only slow bit